# Converting a DataTable to nested JSON output C#

Tags: .net, sql-server, json.net

I have a SQL Server source table defined as:

CstCmpCode         Main_Group          Sub_Group          ClosBal 
 AH01                    Neck Wraps         AFGHANI              7

I need the output to be:

```
{
  "CstCmpCode": "AH01",
  "Main_Group": "Neck Wraps",
  "sub_group": [
    {
      "Sub_Group": "AFGHANI",
      "ClosBal": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the source SQL Server table being imported to a DataSet, then was going to use **`JSON.NET`** to parse the results. I was thinking I should create some sort of Class structure with a main_group having a list of sub_group/closbal key/value pairs, but I'm not totally sure if that's the right track or not.

Thanks. Yogesh.Sharma

Answer (score 2):

you can directly do it by using following code(with Newtonsoft Json.NET).

```
string JSONresult;
JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDataTable);
```

Comment: but, my json string is not getting upgdated with nested json string

Comment: In this case your approach is the right one, for reference your can use this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628569/nested-json-from-datatable

Answer (score 0):

If you need this output you should have a class like this:

```
public class SubGroup
{
    public string Sub_Group { get; set; }
    public int ClosBal { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string CstCmpCode { get; set; }
    public string Main_Group { get; set; }
    public List<SubGroup> sub_group { get; set; }
}
```

An objects of this class can be serialized to the JSON format you mentioned.

Comment: directly it is possible ? without implementing the for loop for datatable